What causes a pitcher to gain special pitches?
In Backyard Baseball '97, pitchers get special pitches it seems after a certain number of successful pitches, or perhaps strikeouts. What is the actual trigger to unlocking a special pitch?

According to the Fandom,

Power-Ups are specials obtained by the players. These are obtained by performing special actions (for example, striking out a batter or making a triple play), however they often deplete the player's stamina.

As Dragonrage noted, it's also possible to get a 110% juice powerup which recovers the pitcher's stamina.

Can confirm. used to play this game a lot. Striking people out gives special pitches (never got a triple play though, so IDK about that). Though one thing to note is you can get a 110% juice powerup which recovers the pitcher's stamina.
